# How do I partition/split a graph evenly?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, graph-theory, partition, a-star

I'm currently trying to parallelize an astar algorithm and I'm trying to split the graph based on the number of processes. The structure of the graph is similar to a grid and Here is my attempt

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
file_path = "grid_graph.txt"
graph = None
assigned_nodes = []

if rank == 0:
    graph = load_graph(file_path)


graph = comm.bcast(graph, root=0)
total_nodes = len(graph)
num_processes = comm.Get_size()


base_num_nodes = total_nodes // num_processes
remaining_nodes = total_nodes % num_processes


start_index = rank * base_num_nodes
end_index = (rank + 1) * base_num_nodes

if rank < remaining_nodes:
    start_index += rank
    end_index += rank + 1
else:
    start_index += remaining_nodes
    end_index += remaining_nodes

assigned_nodes = list(graph.keys())[start_index:end_index]

all_assigned_nodes = comm.gather(assigned_nodes, root=0)

if rank == 0:
    for process_rank, nodes in enumerate(all_assigned_nodes):
        print("Process", process_rank, "assigned nodes:", nodes)
print("Process", rank, "assigned nodes:", assigned_nodes)
start = Node((0, 0))
goal = Node((2, 2))

try:
    start_time = time.time()
    path = astar(start, goal, graph)
    print("Process", rank, "Path found:", path)
    print("Process", rank, "Total cost:", total_cost(path, graph))
    print("Process", rank, "Execution time:", time.time() - start_time, "seconds")
except ValueError:
    print("Process", rank, "No path found")
```

the problem here is that some of the nodes in the subgraphs have no neighbors. How do I partition the graph so that all the nodes in the graph are connected or at least there is a searchable path?

Comment: Please show, for a small simple graph, the input and output that demonstrates the problem.  Also, please clarify "based on the number of processes."  What are these "processes"?

Comment: " nodes in the subgraphs have no neighbors."  Perhaps your question should be: "How to  split a connected graph so every node has at least one neighbor ( no component is smaller than 2)"

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Answer (score 0):

IF

your real question is: "How to split a connected graph so every node as at least one neighbor ( no component is smaller than 2)"

THEN

Do not consider for removal any link that connects a node of degree 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to the details of the algorithms for graph partitioning, then search for  the Louvain algorithm or the Kernighan-Lin algorithm. There are more advanced algorithms, but these two will get you started. You need to be aware that this is a rather complex topic though.

If, instead, you only need to use one graph partitioning algorithm, then search for a graph partitioning library. They are many, including Métis, ParMetis, Zoltan, KaHIP (Karlsruhe High Quality Hypergraph Partitioning, includes many different algorithms), PARTY and Mongoose.